# Breaking a list of character strings into partitions

Tags: r, subset, plyr, data.table

Here is my problem. I have a dataset with 200k rows.

- Each row corresponds to a test conducted on a subject.
- Subjects have unequal number of tests.
- Each test is dated.

I want to assign an index to each test. E.g. The first test of subject 1 would be 1, the second test of subject 1 would be 2. The first test of subject 2 would be 1 etc..

My strategy is to get a list of unique Subject IDs, use lapply to subset the dataset into a list of dataframes using the unique Subject IDs, with each Subject having his/her own dataframe with the tests conducted. Ideally I would then be able to sort each dataframe of each subject and assign an index for each test.

However, doing this over a 200k x 32 dataframe made my laptop (i5, Sandy Bridge, 4GB ram) run out of memory quite quickly.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. If there is not, my only option to overcome the memory limit is to break my unique SubjectID list into smaller sets like 1000 SubjectIDs per list, lapply it through the dataset and at the end of everything, join the lists together. Then, how do I create a function to break my SubjectID list by supplying say an integer that denotes the number of partitions. e.g. BreakPartition(Dataset, 5) will break the dataset into 5 partitions equally.

Here is code to generate some dummy data:

```
UniqueSubjectID <- sapply(1:500, function(i) paste(letters[sample(1:26, 5, replace = TRUE)], collapse =""))
UniqueSubjectID <- subset(UniqueSubjectID, !duplicated(UniqueSubjectID))
Dataset <- data.frame(SubID = sample(sapply(1:500, function(i) paste(letters[sample(1:26, 5, replace = TRUE)], collapse ="")),5000, replace = TRUE))
Dates <- sample(c(dates = format(seq(ISOdate(2010,1,1), by='day', length=365), format='%d.%m.%Y')), 5000, replace = TRUE)
Dataset <- cbind(Dataset, Dates)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that the splitting/lapply is what is using up the memory.  You should consider a more vectorized approach.  Starting with a slightly modified version of your example code:

```
n <- 200000
UniqueSubjectID <- replicate(500, paste(letters[sample(26, 5, replace=TRUE)], collapse =""))
UniqueSubjectID <- unique(UniqueSubjectID)
Dataset <- data.frame(SubID = sample(UniqueSubjectID , n, replace = TRUE))
Dataset$Dates <- sample(c(dates = format(seq(ISOdate(2010,1,1), by='day', length=365), format='%d.%m.%Y')), n, replace = TRUE)
```

And assuming that what you want is an index counting the tests by date order by subject, you could do the following.

```
Dataset <- Dataset[order(Dataset$SubID, Dataset$Dates), ]
ids.rle <- rle(as.character(Dataset$SubID))
Dataset$SubIndex <- unlist(sapply(ids.rle$lengths, function(n) 1:n))
```

Now the 'SubIndex' column in 'Dataset' contains a by-subject numbered index of the tests.  This takes a very small amount of memory and runs in a few seconds on my 4GB Core 2 duo Laptop.

Comment: Running the `ddply` code on your example takes less than a second on my machine (i5 3.2 GHz).

Comment: In my experience, ddply is slower and uses more memory than a vectorized approach.  It sure does have nice syntax though.  I think my machine is substantially slower than yours, I have a Core 2 duo @ 1.8 GHz.  I admit that I didn't speed test initially, but informally comparing the ddply approach vs the rle approach with a few runs and system.time gives run times of 4.2 seconds and 0.9 seconds, respectively, on my computer.

Comment: Probably an approach using `data.table` could even shave more of that time of (I think), especially when the dataset gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: That seems entirely possible.

Comment: Thanks all! This solves my problem and taught me the use of rle. @PaulHiemstra How would you use data.table to speed this up? I tried to make the data frame into a data table and run through the same commands but the difference is negligible.

Comment: If have not worked with `data.table` alot, but if you want feedback, you need to post the `data.table` code you used, e.g. as an edit to your question.

Comment: Ok I think that should be a separate question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a job for the `plyr` package. I would add the index in this way:

```
require(plyr)
system.time(new_dat <- ddply(Dataset, .(SubID), function(dum) {
    dum = dum[order(dum$SubID, dum$Dates), ]
    mutate(dum, index = 1:nrow(dum))
  }))
```

This splits the dataset up into chunks per `SubID`, and adds an index. The new object has all the `SubID` grouped together, and sorted in time. Your example took about 2 seconds on my machine, and used almost no memory. I'm not sure how `ddply` scales to your data size and characteristics, but you could try. I this does not work fast enough, definitely take a look at the `data.table` package. A [blog post of mine](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/) which compares (among others) `ddply` and `data.table` could serve as some inspiration.